# Sorting mongo query by distance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

Given the following code:

```
Meteor.publish('nearestVenues', function(params){
var limit = !!params ? params.limit : 50;
params ? !!params : 50;
if (!!params && !!params.coordinates){
    return Venues.find(
        { 'location.coordinates': 
            { $near :
                { $geometry :
                  { type : "Point" ,
                    coordinates : params.coordinates 
                  },
                    $maxDistance : 6000,
                    spherical: true
                } 
            }   
        }, {limit: limit, sort: 'location.coordinates': -1 });  
} else {
    return Venues.find({}, {limit: limit});
}
});
```

Why am I unable to properly sort the collection once it hits the client? This works up to filtering the query at sort: 'location.coordinates': -1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$near` operator should already sort the results by distance. Just remove the sort option and it should give you the desired results.

From the mongodb documentation:

**Sort Operation**

`$near` sorts documents by distance. If you also include a sort() for the query, sort() re-orders the matching documents, effectively overriding the sort operation already performed by `$near`. When using sort() with geospatial queries, consider using $geoWithin operator, which does not sort documents, instead of $near.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian, I had a feeling that it sorted automatically. Now when I retrieve my results from the server it is *almost* completely sorted but there are a few that seem out of order. I asked another developer and he said it's because data from the server comes back somewhat scattered so sorting on the client may also be necessary. Given that I'm using iron router, how would I achieve this extra sort? By running the same as above again? Where would this go, in the Controller or in the WaitOn hook?